# Click event on jQuery "fly out" menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to create a click event on a jQuery fly out menu. Once you hover to the 2nd or 3rd layer is where I need the event to take place.

I'm also new to jQuery so forgive me if the code isn't up to standards.

I have a sample here: http://jsbin.com/makoreficexe/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood it right, you just want to have a click event inside the sub items of menu.
To do that, you need to find a way to identify the tag that was clicked, and there are a lot of ways.

I'll show you just 3 examples, but there are a lot...

1 - you can have a class for every tag that you want to click.

HTML - specifying a class

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <!-- This is the sub nav -->
        <ul class="listTab">
          <li><a class="About" href="#">About This Template Here</a></li>
          <li><a class="Flash" href="#">Flash</a></li>
          <li><a class="Jquery" href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

Js

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".About").click(function(){
     alert("clicked")
  }),
$(".Flash").click(function(){
     alert("clicked")
  })

});
```

**The problem in this case is that is difficult to manage a lot of classes.**

2 Using Id's

```
<li><a href="#">Home</a>
        <!-- This is the sub nav -->
        <ul class="listTab">
          <li><a id="About" href="#">About This Template Here</a></li>
          <li><a id="Flash" href="#">Flash</a></li>
          <li><a id="Jquery" href="#">jQuery</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $("#About").click(function(){
         alert("clicked")
      }),
    $("#Flash").click(function(){
         alert("clicked")
      })

    });
```

**The problem is that could be harder to manage a lot of ids as well. but i guess that is the better approach for your simple scenario**

3 - You can get it using nth child. the problem is that if you change the structure of your html file, it can "break" your jquery selector.

```
 $("#navList li:nth-child(2)").click(function(e){

    alert(e);
  })
```

Here is a list with a lot of types of jquery selector .

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-selectors.htm

Hope it helps.

Comment: Where would you draw the line on the use of class and id? 10? 20? or 50 sub menus?

Comment: That's a good question, i guess that if you need to have 10 sub menus, something in you UI its not right. I'll be really hard handle this situation. Maybe it will this kinda problem with 20 sub menus jquery will not resolve in a good way..

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.listTab a').click(function(e){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to add "data" attributes to your a tags (http://api.jquery.com/data/).

For example, in the html for your first flyout:

```
<li><a data-whatever="This is in data-whatever" href="#">About This Template Here</a></li>
```

And in your jQuery ready bit, add this:

```
$('.listTab li a').click( function (e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the href="#" in your a tag from firing
    console.log($(this).data('whatever'));
});
```

You can then use the 'data-whatever' attribute in your click function to trigger what needs to happen.

http://jsbin.com/budoqizumuja/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output